# How to avoid  image is Hidden by Button

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have kept an TImage component at the Top-right corner of a bitbutton.While loading of Form  some part of **image is Hidden by Button** as like in image .How to avoid this.? and also tell me **how to find corner of a Button such that i can place my image correctly to show notification correctly in case of Dynamically loaded buttons.**

[image]

Yours **Rakesh.**

Comment: Your client wants iPhone notifications. But what about the fact that your app still uses Windows Classic? You urgently need to start using Mike Lischke's theme manager that comes with Delphi 7.

Answer (score 6):

A TImage cannot be brought in front of a TBitButton since a BitButton is a windowed control (TWinControl). Instead of a TBitBtn or a TButton, you can use a control which does not descend from TWinControl, like a TSpeedButton.

The top-right corner of a button is at (Button.Left + Button.Width, Button.Top).

Comment: Is it possible to use another button rather than Bit Button for my Requirement ?

Comment: @rakesh But keep in mind that the x coordinate (where you want to put your image) relative to the top-left corner of the button is `(Button.Left + Button.Width) - Image.Width`

Comment: @rakesh - Sure. As I see it there're three possibilites - 1) use a button on another button like you said, 2) use a larger control which would fake for an image overlayed on a button, 3) draw notification on a window dc.. 3rd one would be most cumbersome..

Comment: @rakesh - Ah! I now see what you ask.. Yes, you can use a TSpeedButton for instance, which is a TGraphicControl descendant. I included this comment into the answer.

Comment: TSpeedButton is also overriding the Image.could you tell me How you achieved that..?

Comment: @rakesh - Right click on image, Conrol -> Bring To Front.

Comment: @Sertac - That won't work to bring a non-windowed control in front of a windowed control (like a TButton).

Comment: @Jerry - That's what this answer says. The comment is answering how to bring a TImage in front of a TSpeedButton.

Answer (score 0):

A TBitButton owns a window handle and only controls with an own window handle can be placed in front of it. You could place your bitmap on a TPanel (TPanel inherits from TWinControl and has a window handle), and this panel you can bring in front of any other control. Set the BorderStyle of the panel to bsNone, so it only works as a container and is not visible.

P.S. If your bitmap is as simple as the one in your example, you could directly write onto the panel and set the colors accordingly.